# Estimating the $n^{th}$ prime $p_n$ in terms of $n$ for $n$ large

Tags: prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

From the prime number theorem we know that for $n$ large ,

$n=\pi(p_n)\sim\frac{p_n}{\log p_n}$

$\implies \log n \sim \log(p_n)-\log\log p_n \ \ -(i)$

Now $p_n \sim n\log p_n$.
Some calculations with primes between $10000$ and $100000$ makes me feel $p_n \sim n\log n$ holds. To prove this I'd have to show $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{\log \log p_n}{log n}=0$ .So that by $(i)$ I'd be done.

Can someone tell me if my intuition is correct and if so how to prove the step I'm stuck at.Thanks in advance.

Comment: The usual statement of the prime number theorem is $p_n \sim n \log (n)$.  See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem)

Comment: In particular, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Approximations_for_the_nth_prime_number

Comment: $\log (p_n)-\log \log (p_n)\sim \log (p_n)$ so (i) already says what you want

Comment: @tomos Oh, right ,that didn' tclick before. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\pi(x) \sim \frac{x}{\log x}$$
gives
$$\pi(x)\log \pi(x) \sim \frac{x}{\log x}\log (\frac{x}{\log x}) \sim x$$

letting $x=p_n$ gives your result
$$n \log n \sim p_n$$